# How to fix yum update error: "Error: requested datatype primary not available"

Tags: centos7, yum, php-7.3

I'm running a CentOS 7 web server which uses remi repository for updating php version to 7.3.

When I try to update the system using yum:

`yum update`

I get the following error message: *Error: requested datatype primary not available*

### What I tried:

I googled it and found [this solution](https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2018/01/yum-error-requested-datatype-primary-not-available/) and I found that the problem was the remi repository so I ran

`yum clean all --verbose`

then

`yum --disablerepo="remi*" update`

and I could update the system, **all but php 7.3!**

### Additional info:

The content of the repo file located in `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php73.repo` is:

```
# This repository only provides PHP 7.3 and its extensions
# NOTICE: common dependencies are in "remi-safe"

[remi-php73]
name=Remi's PHP 7.3 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/$basearch/
#mirrorlist=https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/httpsmirror
mirrorlist=http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php73-debuginfo]
name=Remi's PHP 7.3 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - debuginfo
baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/debug-php73/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php73-test]
name=Remi's PHP 7.3 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/test73/$basearch/
#mirrorlist=https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/test73/httpsmirror
mirrorlist=http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/test73/mirror
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php73-test-debuginfo]
name=Remi's PHP 7.3 test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - debuginfo
baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/debug-test73/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

which I get installing using the guide on [Remi's website](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

```
yum install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

I edited the file `vim /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php73.repo` and changed the commented lines marked with ->

```
[remi-php73]
name=Remi's PHP 7.3 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/$basearch/
-> mirrorlist=https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/httpsmirror
-> #mirrorlist=http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

It looks like there's some problem with the repo URLs.

Comment: I also needed to update the remi-safe.repo file with the same change!